# How to read latest email conversation HTML body from specific email using Microsoft Exchange webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to read email body part alone from email of inbox.

I need to extract only replied email body instead of whole email body.

e.g.

```
************
A This is good tenant.

Regards,
Test

From:test@gmail.com
To: ----
----------
----------

Hi User, Data has been populated. Please reply with A or R with comments.

Regard
Admin.

************
```

So when I read email body of above email I get the whole body mentioned above. But what I need is only:

```
************
A This is good tenant.

Regards,
Test
************
```

which is having latest replied email body only.

Comment: I don't think EWS has any API for extracting just the new text in the latest response. You could probably get pretty far if you work from the previous message in the conversation though (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn610351(v=exchg.150).aspx). Alternatively you could look at regular .NET (non EWS related) code/libraries that identify and strip everything after the `From:` part. Did you try anything already?

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks. I have tried UniqueBody to read from email, which will return - unique body from whole email body, if null then whole body as retur

1. Even I tried using Reading Email Conversations of specific email.

For each email we can read conversations happened.
and for each conversation of email, we will have index.

So, Suppose below is email replied email to original email to approve/reject data.
****************
A This is good Tenant.

regards,
Test

From:XXX@XXXX.com
.............
.............

Dear User, data created.

Regards,
Admin
*****************

Comment: 1. so when we read body of conversation[0] --Top most/latest - we will get below as body
*****************
A This is good Tenant.

regards,
Test

From:XXX@XXXX.com
.............
.............

Dear User, data created.

Regards,
Admin
**********************

2. and when we read body of conversation[1] -- we will get below as body
**********************
Dear User, Dossier created.

Regards,
CMA
**********************

Comment: I also though of reading everything till **From:** to get latest email body replied. - I am using only EWS.

Comment: I added an answer to show how I was able to retrieve just the new parts. If my approach doesn't work for you, edit your question to include the minimal code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach with `UniqueBody` works for me:

```
// ensure that username, password, domain and smtpAddress are set
var service = new ExchangeService {
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, domain),
};
service.AutodiscoverUrl(smtpAddress, redirect => true);

service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, smtpAddress);
var inbox = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox));
var fir = inbox.FindItems(new ItemView(10));
foreach (var ir in fir) {
    var msg = EmailMessage.Bind(service, ir.Id, new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody));
    Console.WriteLine(msg.UniqueBody.Text);
}
```

For any follow-up message in the results, the `msg.UniqueBody.Text` property contains only the parts that are new in that message.

Note that there might be better ways to do this, but this works in my quick test (against Exchange Online).

Comment: Hi Frank, I have already tried this. Can you please try below.

Comment: Original email contains below body

`Hi User
Regards,
Admin`

----------
Reply to that email is as below.

`Hi`

Comment: As I said: this code works on the Exchange Online where I tested it. If it doesn't work for you, **you** will have to provide a way for me to reproduce your situation. You can do that by editing your question and providing **your** minimal code that you use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either with on premise exchange server 2010 SP3

Comment: This doesn't work for me ,it return all the entrie mail contents only

Comment: Hi Frank. This works just fine with minimal change in exchange service url. Thanks.